# Replace(x, y, z) not working on hyperlinks

Tags: excel, vba

I have workbook with many hyperlinks. Recently workbook was moved to another place (one folder "deeper"). Because of that all hyperlinks messed up and now are:

```
file:///\\company\common\shared\VRS\Program Files\documents\example.doc
```

instead

```
file:///\\company\common\shared\VRS\documents\example.doc
```

I am trying to write a macro to remove \Program Files\ part from all hyperlinks. Found some examples in [here](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T008624_Changing_Huge_Numbers_of_Hyperlinks.html); [here](https://excel.tips.net/T003358_Changing_Portions_of_Many_Hyperlinks.html); [here (stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228195/replace-part-of-hyperlink) and [here (another stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805046/excel-hyperlink-mass-update).

Problem that none of the solution works (nothing is changed) and I am out of ideas what I am doing wrong.

codes I tried:

```
Sub EditHyperlinks()
    Dim lnkH As Hyperlink
    Dim sOld As String
    Dim sNew As String

    sOld = "file:///\\company\common\shared\VRS\Program Files\documents\"
    sNew = "file:///\\company\common\shared\VRS\documents\"

    For Each lnkH In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
        lnkH.Address = Replace(lnkH.Address, sOld, sNew)
        lnkH.TextToDisplay = Replace(lnkH.TextToDisplay, sOld, sNew)
    Next
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub FixHyperlinks2()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim hl As Hyperlink
    Dim sOld As String
    Dim sNew As String

    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    sOld = "file:///\\company\common\shared\VRS\Program Files\documents\"
    sNew = "file:///\\company\common\shared\VRS\documents\"
    For Each hl In wks.Hyperlinks
        hl.Address = Replace(hl.Address, sOld, sNew)
    Next hl
End Sub
```

---

```
 Sub FindReplaceHLinks(sFind As String, sReplace As String, _
        Optional lStart As Long = 1, Optional lCount As Long = -1)

        Dim rCell As Range
        Dim hl As Hyperlink

        For Each rCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
            If rCell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
                For Each hl In rCell.Hyperlinks
                    hl.Address = Replace(hl.Address, sFind, sReplace, lStart, lCount, vbTextCompare)
                Next hl
            End If
        Next rCell
    End Sub

    Sub Doit()

        FindReplaceHLinks "file:///\\company\common\shared\VRS\Program Files\documents\", "file:///\\company\common\shared\VRS\documents\"    
    End Sub
```

---

```
 Sub test()
        Dim hLink As Hyperlink
        Dim wSheet As Worksheet

        For Each wSheet In Worksheets
           For Each hLink In wSheet.Hyperlinks
                hLink.Address = Replace(hLink.Address, "file:///\\company\common\shared\VRS\Program Files\documents\", "file:///\\company\common\shared\VRS\documents\")
            Next hLink
        Next
    End Sub
```

Note that I have tried to write address (probably) all the possible variants: beginning file:///\; \ and without any \

Can somebody point me to right direction?

*P.S. probably I should mention that files are in local network directory.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work, you want to split the text on `\`, look for the text entry, then build the string back up.

```
Function FixFileNames(FileName As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim testarr As Variant
    Dim fixedString As String

    testarr = Split(FileName, "\", , vbBinaryCompare)

    For i = LBound(testarr) To UBound(testarr)
        If Not testarr(i) = "Program Files" Then fixedString = fixedString & "\" & testarr(i)
    Next

    FixFileNames = Right$(fixedString, Len(fixedString) - 1)
End Function

Sub Tester()
    Debug.Print FixFileNames("file:///\\company\common\shared\VRS\Program Files\documents\example.doc")
End Sub
```

Comment: Turns out problem was risen because of dynamic hyperlinks instead of absolute ones ([link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/903163/how-to-create-absolute-hyperlinks-and-relative-hyperlinks-in-word-docu) ) . Because of that all the links was messed up and shortened. Could not find common thing between them to hold on, so ended up fixing most of them manually... In other situation, code you have suggested would have worked as far as I can tell from my testings. Accepting it as an answer, since it helped to get on the right track. Thanks.