# VBA to Replace a Portion of a Hyperlink to Another Sheet In the Same Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get a portion of a link to another sheet within the same workbook changed through VBA.

I have a spreadsheet, where I want the user to be able to change select if they want to see "Site1" or "Site2" by changing the values in cells labeled "Change From" and "Change To".

I have a separate sheets for "Site1" and for "Site2".

So on my main sheet 
if "Change from" is in F4 = "Site1"
and "Change to" is in F5 = "Site2"

I want the corresponding cells to change to reflect Site2 when I run the macro.

So far I have figured out how to change all regular references and formulas to switch to the appropriate sheet. I however, cannot get it to change the portion of the hyperlink that links to the specific sheet:

For example I need only the sheet name to change

from:

```
C:\Documents\test.xlsm - Site1!A1
```

to:

```
C:\Documents\test.xlsm - Site2!A1
```

I tried the following code but it did not work:

I also tried the solutions give here, but they only seem to change the path names, but do not let me change the sheet name.

[Excel Hyperlink mass update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805046/excel-hyperlink-mass-update)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub test()
    Dim hLink As Hyperlink
    Dim wSheet As Worksheet

    For Each wSheet In Worksheets
       For Each hLink In wSheet.Hyperlinks
            hLink.Address = Replace(hLink.Address, "Site1", "Site2")
        Next hLink
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Replace `.Address` with `.SubAddress`

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much!